# How do I stop Vim from pasting my code as a comment?

Tags: command-line

Suppose I copy some code from a place and try to paste it into Vim, it comes as a comment. Is there any way to fix this?

Example:

```haskell
--Return the smaller  thing

p ::forall a. (Eq a)=> [a]-> a->a->a

p z a b | rank z a >= rank z b =b
        | otherwise = a

--Return the bigger thing

g ::forall a. (Eq a)=> [a]-> a->a->a

g z a b | rank z a <= rank z b =b
        | otherwise = a
```

I copy the above code block into Vim and I get :

> [image]

Comment: Welcome to Vi an Vim SE. Please post code as text, not as an image.

Comment: Do you still have something open in your question? How can we help you further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the answers using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons?  It allow the question to rest :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try `:set paste` before you paste (and make sure to `:set nopaste` afterward). If your terminal can communicate via bracketed paste that the insertion comes from a paste, Vim will essentially do this automatically.

The issue comes from seeing the first comment line and trying to extend the comment line when a new line is started; the paste option disables this treatment, among others.

You can also paste from the `*` or `+` registers to interact with the clipboard or selection.

Comment: There’s also useful support for paste-based operations in the unimpaired plugin from tpope

Answer (score 0):

When you paste in insert mode by default (if the `paste` option is unset) the clipboard is inserted like it would have been typed by the user. In particular if you paste in a comment Vim will consider the clipboard as a comment continuation.

To avoid that I recommend to past in Normal mode using either:

- `p` or
- `]p`

Where `]p` paste the content of the clipboard respecting the current indentation.

More information with [:help ]p](https://vimhelp.org/change.txt.html#%5Dp)

Comment: I think you meant “if the paste option is _un_set.”